# Segmentation fault when trying to access a function in from a user library

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, libraries

DoubleLinkedList.h

```
#ifndef _DOUBLE_LINKED_LIST_H
#define _DOUBLE_LINKED_LIST_H

typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long ulong;
typedef void* Object;   
typedef struct _DNode {
    Object data;
    struct _DNode* prev;
    struct _DNode* next;
}DNode;

typedef struct _DoubleLinkedList{
    DNode* head;
    DNode* tail;
    uint length;
    uint elementSize;
}DoubleLinkedList;

DoubleLinkedList* allocDList (uint elementSize);
#endif
```

DoubleLinkedList.c

```
#include "DoubleLinkedList.h"

DoubleLinkedList* allocDList (uint elementSize)
{
    DoubleLinkedList* l;
    l->head = NULL;
    l->tail = NULL;
    l->length = 0;
    l->elementSize = elementSize;
    return l;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "DoubleLinkedList.h"

int main ()
{
    DoubleLinkedList* ab;
    ab = allocDList(10);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this I get a segmentation fault with a core dump.

this is what is required in the assignment.

> DoubleLinkedList* allocDList(uint elementSize): this function allocates the DoubleLinkList

Comment: in `allocDList`, `l` is uninitialised. You'll want to allocate some memory for the new node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialised `l`, so `l->HEAD`won't work. You can initialise it using `malloc` as:

```
DoubleLinkedList* l = malloc(sizeof(DoubleLinkedList));
```

Also, in the `main` function, once you are done using the variable `ab`, remember to release the memory used by it using the `free` function as follows:

```
int main ()
{
 DoubleLinkedList* ab;
 ab = allocDList(10);

 //Processing here

 free(ab); //Release once it is no longer needed

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(DoubleLinkedList*)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the structure. And don't cast the return from `malloc()`. Did you mean `sizeof(DoubleLinkedList)`?

Comment: Why is the cast not needed?

Comment: This link provides an excellent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1):

Update DoubleLinkedList.c as:

```
DoubleLinkedList* allocDList (uint elementSize)
{
    DoubleLinkedList* l;
    l = malloc(sizeof(DoubleLinkedList));
    l->head = NULL;
    l->tail = NULL;
    l->length = 0;
    l->elementSize = elementSize;
    return l;
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged in 'c' hence new may not be used.

Answer (score 1):

> DoubleLinkedList* l;

You need to allocate some memory to `l`

```
l = (DoubleLinkedList*) malloc(sizeof(DoubleLinkedList));
```